# Подсчет градиентов в градиентном спуске

Tags: python-3.x, математика, numpy, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Помогите найти ошибку в формуле градиентов. Вот, как их считаю я:

```
dw2 = - (2 / n) * np.dot(self.A[1].T,  2 * (self.A[2] - Y))
db2 = - (2 / n) * np.sum(self.A[2] - Y)
delta = self.A[1] - self.A[2]
dw1 = - (2 / n) * np.dot(X.T, delta)
db1 = - (2 / n) * np.sum(self.A[1] - self.A[2])
self.params['w2'] -= self.lr * dw2
self.params['b2'] -= self.lr * db2
self.params['w1'] -= self.lr * dw1
self.params['b1'] -= self.lr * db1
```

A1 - выход скрытого слоя нейросети, A2 - ответ после сигмоиды (A - это словарь с ключами 1 и 2). Использую lr = 0.01 (пробовал от 0.1 до 1e-5), архитектура сети: linear(out_size = 8) -> ReLU ->linear(out_size = 1) -> sigmoid.
При обучении график потерь выглядит как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а язык программирования-то какой? укажите его в виде метки, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ошибка в чём? Какая библиотека? Какой класс у объекта `self`? Распишите ваш вопрос подробнее.

Comment: Ошибка не в коде, у меня проблема именно в математической части. Я оформил свою сеть как класс и сделал ее параметры полями класса